# How to know Swiper.js is not moving? (velocity = 0)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, touch-event, swiper.js

I'm using Swiper.js in my React project. It's in swipeable free mode with autoplay. I will stop the autoplay when `touchstart` event is triggered, and resume the autoplay after `touchend`.

However, it'll be awkward if the autoplay resumes immediately after the user release their finger since there's still momentum velocity caused by the swipe. I wonder if there's a way to detect the swiper stops, i.e. the velocity equals zero. I think the proper timing to resume autoplay is after the swiper stops for a while.

The following is my current workaround, wait 1 second until resuming the autoplay: (I also purposely slow down the momentum effect)

```js
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";
// Import Swiper React components
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";

// Import Swiper styles
import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/bundle";
import "swiper/css/free-mode"
import "swiper/css/pagination"
import "./App.css";

// import Swiper core and required modules
import SwiperCore, {
  Autoplay,
  FreeMode, Pagination
} from 'swiper';

// install Swiper modules
SwiperCore.use([FreeMode, Autoplay, Pagination]);

export default function App() {

  const swiperRef = useRef(null);
  let disableAutoPlayTimer = null;

  useEffect(() => {
    const swiper = swiperRef.current;
    // subscribe event
    swiper.addEventListener("touchstart", touchStartHandler);
    swiper.addEventListener("touchend", touchEndHandler);
    return () => {
      // unsubscribe event
      swiper.removeEventListener("touchstart", touchStartHandler);
      swiper.removeEventListener("touchend", touchEndHandler);
    };
  }, []);

  const touchStartHandler = (e) => {
    swiperRef.current.swiper.autoplay.stop();
  }

  const touchEndHandler = (e) => {
    // I'm now using a timer to wait 1 second for the swiper to stop
    if (!disableAutoPlayTimer) {
      disableAutoPlayTimer = setTimeout(() => {
        swiperRef.current.swiper.autoplay.start();
        disableAutoPlayTimer = null;
      }, 1000);
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Swiper
        dir="rtl"
        slidesPerView="auto"
        spaceBetween={30}
        freeMode={{
          enabled: true,
          momentumVelocityRatio: 0.5
        }}
        loop={true}
        loopedSlides={9}
        grabCursor={true}
        autoplay={{
          "delay": 0,
          "disableOnInteraction": false
        }}
        speed={1000}
        className="mySwiper"
        ref={swiperRef}
      >
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide><span style={{color: 'red'}}>Slide 3</span></SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 5</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 6</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 7</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 8</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 9</SwiperSlide>
      </Swiper>
    </>
  )
}
```

All in all, my question is, "**How to know the current velocity of Swiper.js**?", or "**How do I know the swiper is not moving**?"
Any idea?